# "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findAll')"

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, babeljs

stack stack!! help
this is the model:

```
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Skill extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of DataTypes lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  Skill.init(
    {
      id:{
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
     allowNull: false,
     primaryKey:true
    },
     s_name: {
     type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
     allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'skill',
      tableName: 'Skills'
    }
  );
  return Skill;
};
```

and this is service

```
import {Skill} from "models";
class SkillService{
static async createNewSkill (data){
  try {
        const newskill = await Skill.create(data, {
          fields: ["id", "s_name"],
        });
        return newskill;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
      }
}
static async fetchAllSkills(){
  try {
    const users = await Skill.findAll({
      order: [["id", "DESC"]],
      attributes: { exclude: ["updatedAt"] },
    });
    return users;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
}
export default SkillService;
```

i have tried many things but still i am getting an error.another model that i am having is working properly with its service. can anyone help me please, anyone who can know the origin of this error.

Comment: You need to add in more details to your question. Also to add exactly on which line the error occurs will help.

Answer (score 0):

You import `Skill` in the module, that's fine, the scope of it it's reachable in your function.

Now, if you import your `SkillService` in another module like this: `import {SkillService} from ...` then there is the problem, because if you do not use `require` then you're just importing that piece of code, without executing the module, therefor you do not import `Skill` in the module where you use your `SkillService` class. By calling it's static methods, the imported class doesn't have any idea of your import in its declaration module, since you imported only the class from there.

A solution would be to export the class using `export` keyword and in the module you want to use it use `require` function.
Another solution would be to import the model all over the place where you import your `SkillService` class (not indicated)